# Prove $A^{c}\cup B=U\implies A\subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the case of $\, p\in U\implies p\in A^{c}\cup B\,$,

$$\begin{align}
p\in A  & \implies  p\in A\; \land\; \color{red}{p\in U}\\
 & \implies p\in A\;\land\;\color{red}{(p\in A^{c}\;\lor\; p\in B)} \\
 & \implies (p\in A\;\land\; p\in A^{c})\;\lor\;(p\in A\;\land\; p\in B) \\
 & \implies p\in A\;\land\; p\in B \\
 & \implies p\in B.\\
 \end{align}$$

However, when it comes to $p\in A^{c}\cup B\implies p\in U$, I don't know where to start from. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: What does "$U\implies A^c\cup B$" mean?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry if that makes you puzzled. It means $p\in U\implies p\in A^{c}\cup B$.

Comment: Is U the biggest set ? I mean do $ A,B \in U$ ?

Comment: @JohnMath $U$ is universal set.

Comment: It does not matter if it makes me puzzled. It's just bad writing which is more likely to come back to bite you rather than me.

Comment: Its still not clear.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli My bad. I edited it.

Comment: The same proof can be made if you start with $p\in A^c\cup B$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I suspect that would result in $\color{red}{p}\in A^c\cup B\implies \color{red}{p}\in A^c\cup B\;\land\; \color{red}{q}\in A$. In other words, $p\ne q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A^{c}\cup B=U$

Let $x\in A$ we have $x\in U$ so $x \in A^{c} \cup B$ and $x\notin A^{c}$ so $x \in B$, i.e. $A \subset B$

So we have : $A^{c}\cup B=U\implies A\subseteq B$

Comment: How do you go from $x\in U\implies x\in A^{c}\cup B$?

Comment: $A^{c}\cup B=U\implies A\subseteq B$ so we assume $A^{c}\cup B=U$

Comment: I was a mess. Sorry!!!!!!!!!!! Would you edit your answer so that I can withdraw the downvote, and accept your answer?

Comment: It is done, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

Using De MOrgan's Law we get $$\begin{align}
A^c\cup B=U&\implies (A^c\cup B)^c=U^c\\
&\implies A\cap B^c=\emptyset\\
&\implies A\subset B.
\end{align}$$

Comment: That also necessitates the proof for $A\cap B^{c}=\emptyset\implies A\subseteq B$. I, of course, intuitively understand that works, but I'm now proving a theorem. In fact, the theorem is about proving the set of statements ($A\cap B^{c}=\emptyset$, $A\subseteq B$, and so on) equivalent.